# Вывод разного количества изображений как вконтакте

Tags: android, recyclerview, picasso, gridlayoutmanager, universal-image-loader

Нужно, чтобы было примерно как в вконтакте .

Кто нибудь может подсказать или подтолкнуть к реализации:

Размеры изображений по ширине разные, как и их количество(в одном ряду может быть разное количество), по высоте в ряд изображения не изменяются.

1. Что использовать для вывода изображений GridView или RecyclerView(GridLayoutManager)?
2. Как выводить пустые placeholder до загрузки изображения с соотвествующими размерами. Приходит только одно на ум. Передавать сначала коллекцию размеров(ширина/высота) и "прорисововать" эти размеры до загрузки для каждого изображения, а потом асинхронно выводить их, после загрузки.
3. Чтобы быстро скролилось без задержек.
4. На чем это лучше сделать: на чистом Андроиде, Universal Image Loader, Picasso.

Я пробовал Universal Image Loader и GridLayoutManager, но wrap_content в RecyclerView работает плохо. Еще Universal Image Loader больше не обновляют.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514887/layoutmanager-for-recyclerview-grid-with-different-cell-width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 1 RecyclerView - старайтесь использовать его для любых задач со списками. Не знаю, в каких случаях может понадобиться что-то кроме него.
- 2,3,4. Glide все это умеет

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, а о Fresco что нибудь слышали/пробовали, он относительно новый еще

Comment: Я чиал материалы, в которых Fresco сравнивался с Glide. Результаты не в пользу первого